# What does "off to" mean?

Tags: meaning

There is [a book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1427640262) titled *Off to a Flying Start: Horsing Around the Language*. What does *off to* mean?

I did some research on it and I feel it means *going to do*, but I still need your confirmation.

Comment: There's a specialised meaning in horse racing; *they're off* is the traditional cry as a race starts, and the start itself is often called *the off*.

Comment: We're off to see the wizard, The Wonderful Wizard of Oz /
We hear he is a whiz of a wiz, if ever a wiz there was

Comment: _Hi ho, Hi ho! It's off to work we go._

Comment: @TimLymington - It's not just in horse racing, and the cry is usually, `And they're OFF!` ^_^

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See a few examples below.

- I'm off to Canada next week.
- I'm off to do my homework.

It can have several meanings. Most of the time, it means you're **going to** (not *going to **do***). In the first sentence *I'm off to Canada next week*, you're going to Canada the following week. In the second, you're leaving where ever you are to proceed to do your homework.

It has more of a informal atmosphere a large percentage of the time and is used in conversational talk mostly. If you're having a talk with somebody and you want to end the conversation, you may say "Well, I'm off to take the kids to school" instead of "I'm going to go and take the kids to school."

Another usage of the phrase *off to* can be seen below.

- I'm off to a good start, but I still need to focus a lot in order to win.
- He's off to a good start in the race, but can he keep it up?

These sentences use *off to* as "beginning with" and, for example, the first sentence's *off to* can be replaced with "I'm beginning with a good start, but ..."

Comment: May I suggest that in all these *off* means "leave" or "depart"? With an infinitive verb (*to do something*) or a place (*to somewhere*) the sense is "leaving" now (or in the future). With *to a good* (or bad) *start*, however, the sense is "have left" -- *e.g.*, the starting gate, in the racing idiom, or launchpoint.