# What are the good expressions for " going to school or going to work"?

Tags: expressions

I think when someone leaves home, he or she may say like this, " I am leaving" or "I am going to school" or "I am going to work" . I am wondering what phrases native speakers usually say when they leave home for work or school.

Answer (score 4):

Not a native speaker here, but I used to say "I'm **heading out to/for** school"

*According to thefreedictionary:*

> Definition(head out for something): to set out for something or some place; to begin a journey to
>   something or some place

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/head+out

Comment: +1 For "I'm leaving" in general, without naming the place you're going, I'd use "I'm heading out the door".

Answer (score 1):

***Be/go off to school/work*** are idiomatic expressions:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20off%20to%20school%2Coff%20to%20work&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20to%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coff%20to%20work%3B%2Cc0): off to school/work

See also [What does “off to” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81714/what-does-off-to-mean)